# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "root" failed could not translate host name "-U" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to download a database using `pg_dump` and executing the command below

```
PGPASSWORD=$DATABASE_PASSWORD pg_dump --no-owner -x -Fc $DATABASE_NAME -h $DATABASE_HOST -U $DATABASE_USERNAME > staging_29_jul_2020.dump
```

but this is giving me an error

`pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "root" failed: could not translate host name "-U" to address: Name or service not known`

my database name and user name  are different and are not root.

any help on how to fix this would be really great.

Thanks.

Comment: Since it thinks that the argument to -h  is the string `-U`, I can only conclude that the variable `$DATABASE_HOST` is unset or set to the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) the database name must be the last parameter unless you provide the name through the `-d` parameter:

```
pg_dump --no-owner -x -Fc -d $DATABASE_NAME -h $DATABASE_HOST -U $DATABASE_USERNAME > staging_29_jul_2020.dump
                           ^-- here
```